# .htpasswd permission problem

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a site that needs to be protected with `.htaccess` file.

But I get permission denied error while accessing my site ignoring the correct login. 
Apache Server version: Apache/2.2.3

`.htaccess` file :

```
[root@server conf]# cat /home/molly/www/.htaccess   
AuthName "Directory Auth for User Molly"  
AuthType Basic  
AuthUserFile /home/molly/.htpasswd  
require user molly
```

Permissions :

```
[root@server conf]# ls -al /home/molly/www/.htaccess   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 molly apache 116 Jan 13 18:12 /home/molly/www/.htaccess  
[root@server conf]#
```

Earlier the permissions were 644 to `htaccess` file, but I changed it to 755 after checking some solutions, but of no use

Similarly, permissions on `.htpasswd` file :

```
[root@server conf]# ls -al /home/molly/.htpasswd   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 molly apache 46 Jan 13 18:58 /home/molly/.htpasswd  
[root@server conf]#
```

Error log file :

```
[Wed Jan 14 11:59:29 2015] [error] [client 10.0.0.7] (13)Permission denied:   Could not open password file: /home/molly/.htpasswd  
[Wed Jan 14 11:59:29 2015] [error] [client 10.0.0.7] access to /~molly failed,  reason: verification of user id 'molly' not configured
```

Also I changed the user directory permission to 755 as such, but of no use.

```
[root@server conf]# ls -ld /home/molly/  
drwxr-xr-x 4 molly molly 4096 Jan 13 18:23 /home/molly/  
[root@server conf]#
```

I am unable to move forward because of this weird htpasswd problem.

Any Ideas
I hope many guys might have gone through this problem.

Comment: It may be an SELinux issue.

Comment: does it mean if selinux is enabled, it is never possible to login with correct permissions and settings. Is it possible to make changes in selinux policy so that changes will work with selinux enabled.

Comment: selinux can prevent e.g. apache from reading files in your home directory, even though the permissions say it can. Modifying this is possible, but I don't know how as I've not had any experience with selinux.

Comment: It could also be simple permissions on `/home/molly`. Try `ls -ld /home /home/molly` and ensure that your Apache user (or group) has got at least `x` access into both these directories. The `.htaccess` file itself does not need `x` permission so you can reset that back to `0644`.

Answer (score 1):

(I see this is an old question, but this might be useful to others, so...)

If you suspect a SELinux issue, there is often an easy way to fix it without completely disabling SELinux.

First, make sure that the package that contains the SELinux policy documentation is installed. In RedHat/CentOS/OEL it is named `selinux-policy-doc`.

Then, each system service that is included in the standard distribution has a man page that describes the SELinux context labels and other necessary details for that specific service. They are all named `<service name>_selinux`.

In this case, the command would be `man httpd_selinux`.

In the `BOOLEANS` section of the man page, there will usually be a number of SELinux restrictions that can be easily switched on and off as necessary. Most common needs can be satisfied by adjusting the appropriate booleans as needed. Here's some examples on `httpd`:

> If you want to allow httpd to use built in scripting (usually php), you must turn on the `httpd_builtin_scripting` boolean. Enabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting 1
```

> If you want to allow httpd cgi support, you must turn on the httpd_enable_cgi boolean. Enabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi 1
```

> If you want to allow httpd to read user content, you must turn on the httpd_read_user_content boolean. Disabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

> If you want to allow httpd to read home directories, you must turn on the httpd_enable_homedirs boolean. Disabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
```

> If you want to allow httpd to access cifs file systems, you must turn on the httpd_use_cifs boolean. Disabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_cifs 1
```

> If you want to allow httpd to access nfs file systems, you must turn on the httpd_use_nfs boolean. Disabled by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs 1
```

There are many more SELinux booleans for `httpd`.

To allow `httpd` to access the users' home directories, you'd need at least `httpd_read_user_content`. And since your error log indicates you're probably using Apache's `UserDir` feature, so you'll need `httpd_enable_homedirs` too. 
[See also this question on Server Fault.](https://serverfault.com/q/461504/442837)

Both are disabled by default, so you'll need two commands:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
# setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
```

The `-P` option to `setsebool` tells it to make the settings persistent, so there will be no need to edit any further SELinux configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

To see from what exactly is your problem try with 777 permissions, then change back to 644 or 444. If with 777 permissions you get the same error, try to disable SELinux

/etc/selinux/config

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

If again not working try to remove .htpasswd, if now work correctly, it means the problem is in .htpasswd, for example rules or some grammatical error.

Comment: Ouch! Never "disable" SELinux, unless you definitely want to disable. Use `setenforce 0` to switch to permissive mode. Or better, check /var/log/audit/audit.log!